# Terminal condition for JDBC preparedStatement.executeBatch()

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, batch-processing

I am using java.sql library to execute updates in batches.
When preparedStatement.executeBatch() is executed, ideally it should return an array of update counts.

But in some instances, instead of update counts it returns -2, like below..

```
 /**
 * The constant indicating that a batch statement executed successfully
 * but that no count of the number of rows it affected is available.
 *
 * @since 1.4
 */
int SUCCESS_NO_INFO = -2;
```

So in this case, when I am running the queries in batches, there's no way to find whether a particular batch query execution updated any records or not. So there's no way to determine a terminal condition to exit the loop of batch execution. If anyone has a workaround or suggestion. It would be helpful.

I have the below condition right now.

```
  private static String batchUpdate() throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    String result = null;

    String updateSQL = "update TABLE_NAME set SOME_FLAG ='T' \n" +
            " where SOME_USER!='SOMEUSER' and SOME_FLAG = 'F' and rownum<=?";

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateSQL);

        dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

        while (true) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 10000);
            preparedStatement.addBatch();
            int[] updateResults = preparedStatement.executeBatch();
            if (updateResults == null || updateResults.length == 0 || updateResults[0] == -3) {
                break;
            }
            dbConnection.commit();
        }

        result = "Records are updated!";
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
        dbConnection.rollback();
    } finally {
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Actually, can you post more of your code? I don't think you are supposed to store the results in an array.

Comment: @AlvinBunk
Added the entire method

Comment: I don't see why you're using `executeBatch()`  at all if there is only one update in the batch. I also don't see the point of the loop.

Comment: It's a batch of 10000 records in one iteration. If you see the sql, it is filtered based on rowNum

Comment: So you don't need the batch. The idea of adding batches is that you add more than one. What you're doing is pointless. You may as well use `executeUpdate()` directly.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the clarification. Will try that and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oracle 11g does not return update counts](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28767) for batch methods. Instead it returns SUCCESS_NO_INFO.

Answer (score -2):

I looked at some examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), and I think you'll have to catch an exception in your code.

So this means a complete redesign of your code.
Look at the tutorial link. I think it shouldn't be that hard for you.

Also, do a rollback if you get an exception!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it won't throw an exception if there are no records to be updated. side note: I didn't downvote.